# Problema al usar margin en bootstrap 5.0.2

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

**Hola! Resulta que estoy implementando un carrusel de imagenes en una landing page y tengo el siguiente problema**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver en la imagen el boton derecho está saliendo del div, el izquierdo lo puse solucionar aplicando estas etiquestas el codigo

La etiqueta `carousel-control-prev position-absolute top-50 start-0 translate-middle` se encarga de centrar el boton izquierdo al medio y a la izquierda del contenedor y la etiqueta `ms-3` le da un margin-left de 3

El problema viene ahora cuando quiero hacer lo mismo con el boton derecho, aplico la misma logica pero a la inversa, `carousel-control-next position-absolute top-50 start-100 translate-middle` se encarga de centrarlo al medio y a la derecha pero cuando quiero usar un margin-right usando la etiqueta `me-3` no se mueve.

**A continuación les dejo el codigo completo**

```
<button
    class="carousel-control-prev position-absolute top-50 start-0 translate-middle ms-3"
    type="button"
    data-bs-target="#carouselExampleInterval"
    data-bs-slide="prev"
  >
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button
    class="carousel-control-next position-absolute top-50 start-100 translate-middle "
    type="button"
    data-bs-target="#carouselExampleInterval"
    data-bs-slide="next"
  >
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
```

Comment: Porqué le aplicas `position-absolute top-50 start-0 translate-middle`? Las clases `.carousel-control-*` ya tienen esos valores dentro de sus propiedades. `position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 15%;
    padding: 0;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    background: 0 0;
    border: 0;
    opacity: .5;
    transition: opacity .15s ease;
left: 0;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola puedes usar margen negativos pero debes habilitarlo en Sass en la siguiente propiedad a true:
$enable-negative-margins: true;
Puedes encontrar mas informacion en la documentacion oficial de Boostraps 5.0